# How to generate Row Number Column for each occurrence of an ID in a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to count each occurrence of an ID in a column as new column.
It should look like this:

[image]

I tried it with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) as rownum`
but it did not work.

Can you guy please help me out?

Comment: You need a `PARTITION BY` clause. Have a look at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) in the documentation.

Comment: As Larnu is suggesting, just switch the `ORDER BY` with `PARTITION BY` and you'll have what you need. You are wanting to partition records by ID, order is irrelevant.

Comment: @JNevill the `ORDER BY` clause is a compulsory cause in the `OVER` for `ROW_NUMBER` so just changing `ORDER` to `PARTITION` would generate an error. Of course, the OP could just use an arbitrary value to order by though (which it seems they are happy with based on the image).

Answer (score 2):

In order to reset the numbering for each change of `ID`, you need a `PARTITION BY` clause.

There appears to be no specific ordering within the partitions, so you can use `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`. If you have another column you want to order the numbering by, use that instead.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rownum
```